# Vault is already initialized error message

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I deployed the following helm chart for vault and I get the following error "Vault is already initialized" when doing "vault operator init" command.  I do not understand why it is already initialized.
Also, when I enable readinessProbe the pod keeps restating I assume because it is not initialized properly.

```
global:
 enabled: true
 tlsDisable: false
server:
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/ca.crt
  logLevel: debug
  logFormat: standard
  readinessProbe:
   enabled: false
  authDelegator:
    enabled: true
  extraVolumes:
  - type: secret
    name: vault-server-tls # Matches the ${SECRET_NAME} from above
 standalone:
  enabled: true
  config: |
   listener "tcp" {
     address = "[::]:8200"
     cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
     tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/tls.crt"
     tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/tls.key"
    }

  storage "file" {
    path = "/vault/data"
  }
```

Comment: have you tried removing the folder /vault/data if that already exists, and try the init?